# libGdx: Sprite is not drawn when there is a stage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm sure I'm missing something VERY obvious here, but I'm  beginner so don't crush me please. My problem is that I have a stage that has a viewport small than the screen. Now I also want to draw a Sprite on the screen directly using Sprite.draw(SpriteBatch). The position of the Sprite and the stage don't overlap. The stage is drawn just fine, but the Sprite is not visible. When I comment out the stage.draw() part in the render-method, then the Sprite is visible.

Code:
This is my render-method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.851f, 0.894f, 0.992f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    stage.act(delta);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    logoSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Here, I initialize the camera and stage (stageHeight is an int that is just 3/5*the height of the screen):

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, SwapItGame.WIDTH, SwapItGame.HEIGHT);
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setViewport(1080, stageHeight, true, 0, 0, 1080, stageHeight); //The button part of the menu takes up 3 fifth of the Height of hte screen
    stage.setCamera(camera);
```

Here I initialize my Sprite (The position value for the sprite is rather complex, just ignore it. It's certainly above the stage):

```
        logoSprite = skin.getSprite("logo");
        logoSprite.setPosition((SwapItGame.WIDTH-logoSprite.getWidth())/2, (SwapItGame.HEIGHT-stageHeight-logoSprite.getHeight())/2 + stageHeight);
```

Is is impossible to have a Sprite and a stage on the same Screen? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: post the code... else we need to look into the glas ball and see what we can guess

Comment: It's rather long, but I'll of course do it if it helps you.

Comment: then just show us the parts of the render and the part where you add the sprite. without code we cant help you because we dont see what you have done wrong.

Comment: @MGDroid I did that but it doesn't help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try moving

```
stage.draw();
```

above batch operations

```
stage.draw();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
logoSprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Can you maybe explain why it works?

Comment: yea because a Stage has its own batch! so you need to end your batch befor you use the `stage.draw()`. Else you have concurency with batches.

Comment: I am not sure :) batch.begin() batch.end() is a block of code that draws things on screen, I just figured stage.draw() might affect this process

Comment: But when I do it this way, the touch events are located incorrectly :(

Comment: Try putting it below where u set ur camera, but before u set `batch.begin`

Comment: what do you mean by setting the camera?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in the case that you can't or don't want to move your stage.draw() method, just call batch.end() right before your stage.draw(), then restart your batch immediately...I am using separate game screen states for different things in my game and tried to move my stage.draw() around and it only broke other things within my class so I finally just tried this, which worked like a charm and may help someone if the above solution doesn't work easily.

```
batch.end();
stage.draw();
batch.begin();
```